# Pandas Datetime index from range index

Tags: pandas

I have a collection of transactions with a date and a price column:

```
+---------------------------+-------+
|           Date            | Price |
+---------------------------+-------+
| 2016-05-27 10:02:24+00:00 |  2.90 |
| 2016-05-27 10:02:24+00:00 | 14.90 |
| 2016-05-29 07:47:09+00:00 | 12.90 |
| 2016-05-29 11:56:32+00:00 | 16.90 |
| 2016-05-29 22:10:08+00:00 | 11.92 |
+---------------------------+-------+
```

as it is possible to understand from the table not every day a transaction happened, and in some cases several transactions happened the same day.

My question is: how can I create a DataFrame with dates from the oldest transaction to the newest and add to this DataFrame missing dates with `price` 0, while keepping multiple rows for transaction that happened in the same day? A better example will be in the following table:

```
+---------------------------+-------+
|           Date            | Price |
+---------------------------+-------+
| 2016-05-27 10:02:24+00:00 |  2.90 |
| 2016-05-27 10:02:24+00:00 | 14.90 |
| 2016-05-28 00:00:00+00:00 |  0.00 |
| 2016-05-29 07:47:09+00:00 | 12.90 |
| 2016-05-29 11:56:32+00:00 | 16.90 |
| 2016-05-29 22:10:08+00:00 | 11.92 |
+---------------------------+-------+
```

I have tried to create a series with DateRange from the oldest to the newest, and then adding the series to the DataFrame, but doing this leads to having some missing values:

```
d2 = pd.Series(pd.date_range(min(df.Date), max(df.Date)))

df['dates'] = d2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find which dates are missing, then concatenate the missings back

```
import pandas as pd

missings = [x for x in pd.date_range(df.Date.min().date(), df.Date.max().date(), freq='1D').date
            if x not in df.Date.dt.date.unique()]

df = (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(missings).tz_localize('UTC'), 'Price': 0})])
        .sort_values('Date'))
```

#### Output:

```
                       Date  Price
0 2016-05-27 10:02:24+00:00   2.90
1 2016-05-27 10:02:24+00:00  14.90
0 2016-05-28 00:00:00+00:00   0.00
2 2016-05-29 07:47:09+00:00  12.90
3 2016-05-29 11:56:32+00:00  16.90
4 2016-05-29 22:10:08+00:00  11.92
```

---

Also possible to find the missing dates with sets, should be a bit faster

```
missings = list(set(pd.date_range(df.Date.min().date(), df.Date.max().date(), freq='1D', tz='UTC').values) 
                 - set(df.Date.dt.normalize().values))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Series with that min-max `daterange`, outer merge and fillna with 0:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
rng = pd.date_range(start=df.Date.min(), end=df.Date.max(), freq='D')
df = df.set_index('Date')
pd.merge(df, pd.Series(index=rng, name='rng'), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('rng', 1).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
    Price
2016-05-27 10:02:24     2.900
2016-05-27 10:02:24     14.900
2016-05-28 10:02:24     0.000
2016-05-29 07:47:09     12.900
2016-05-29 10:02:24     0.000
2016-05-29 11:56:32     16.900
2016-05-29 22:10:08     11.920
```

Note that I ignored the UTC offsets for convenience, I don't think it should affect my solution. Also note that your times for the interpolated days will be the same as your minimum date.